# how to apply one-many and many-one annotations(Java Persistence)

Tags: java, mysql

I have two tables as follows:

table1:

```
CREATE TABLE `Product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `typename` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `typecode` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=396 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

table2:

```
CREATE TABLE measurements (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    age_group varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    articleType NOT NULL,
    dimension text ,
    createdOn int(11) NOT NULL,
    updatedOn int(11) NOT NULL,
    createdBy text NOT NULL,
)ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=396 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Now how can I join the two tables with join `column measurements.articleType = product.typename` in Java Persistence.

I know the concept of using one to many and many to one using foreign key(http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany). But the above tables does not have foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `JPQL or HQL Native SQL` to achieve that. To use `Query` or `Named Query` you need to associate the entities together.

Since it is not possible in your case, the `Native SQL` is the only option.

But consider creating `constraints` between tables to preserve the `data integrity`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm here assuming you want a Many-to-Many.
In java, if you want it to be bidirectional, use a

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products")
public List<Product> getProducts() { ... }
```

and in Product

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "product_measurement")
public List<Measurement> getMeasurement() { ... }
```

In sql it will be :

```
CREATE TABLE product_measurement
(
product_measurement_id int(11) NOT NULL,
measurement_product_id int(11) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (measurement_product_id) REFERENCES measurement (id),
FOREIGN KEY (product_measurement) REFERENCES product (id)
);
```

Comment: Read this for more info : http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany

Comment: @francesko cannot it be done with out the construction of extra table in the database?

Comment: Not a many-to-many. You could achieve one-to-many or many-to-one by altering the original tables and adding an extra column for foreign keys.